# Matching if any keyword from a list is present in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of keywords. A sample is:

```
 ['IO', 'IO Combination','CPI Combos']
```

Now what I am trying to do is see if any of these keywords is present in a string. For example, if my string is: `there is a IO competition coming in Summer 2018`. So for this example since it contains `IO`, it should identify that but if the string is `there is a competition coming in Summer 2018` then it should not identify any keywords.

I wrote this Python code but it also identifies `IO` in `competition`:

```
if any(word.lower() in string_1.lower() for word in keyword_list):
                    print('FOUND A KEYWORD IN STRING')
```

I also want to identify which keyword was identified in the string (if any present). What is the issue in my code and how can I make sure that it matches only complete words?

Comment: @usr2564301: Please do so. Also, I'd be interested in a pure non-regex solution.

Comment: @Jan: since there is no cumbersome punctuation (comma's or (semi-)colons), a bog standard `split` could be used. It's fairly trivial so I won't suggest that as an answer. (Hah! you mention that punctuation as well. Here, have my last vote of the day )

Comment: @usr2564301: Nope, try a split in combination with `CPI Combos` (see my notes below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Regex solution

You'll need to implement word boundaries here:

```
import re

keywords = ['IO', 'IO Combination','CPI Combos']

words_flat = "|".join(r'\b{}\b'.format(word) for word in keywords)
rx = re.compile(words_flat)

string = "there is a IO competition coming in Summer 2018"
match = rx.search(string)

if match:
    print("Found: {}".format(match.group(0)))
else:
    print("Not found")
```

---

Here, your list is joined with `|` and `\b` on both sides.
Afterwards, you may search with `re.search()` which prints `"Found: IO"` in this example.

---

Even shorter with a direct comprehension:

```
rx = re.compile("|".join(r'\b{}\b'.format(word) for word in keywords))
```

---

#### Non-regex solution

Please note that you can even use a non-regex solution **for single words**, you just have to reorder your comprehension and use `split()` like

```
found = any(word in keywords for word in string.split())

if found:
    # do sth. here
```

---

#### Notes

The latter has the drawback that strings like

```
there is a IO. competition coming in Summer 2018
#         ---^---
```

won't work while they do count as a "word" in the regex solution (hence the approaches are yielding different results). Additionally, because of the `split()` function, combined phrases like `CPI Combos` cannot be found. The regex solution has the advantage to even support lower and uppercase scenarios (just apply `flag = re.IGNORECASE`).

It really depends on your actual requirements.

Comment: @heemayl: Found a drawback for the non-regex solution: combined phrases like `CPI Combos` cannot be found because of `split()`.

Comment: so for non-regex version with ignorecase the search will be - `flag.search(string)`?

Comment: Also how do I identify which keyword was present in the String?

Answer (score -2):

```
for index,key in enumerate(mylist):
      if key.find(mystring) != -1:
         return index
```

It loops over your list, on every item in the list, it checks if your string is contained in the item, if it does, [find()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm) returns -1 which means it is contained, and if that happens, you get the index of the item  where it was found with the help of [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: I think this should be `mystring.find(key)` if `key` is the substring you are looking for.  But even with that change, this just seems like a less pythonic version of the attempt that the OP listed.